# How could I enable hibernation on a Dell Inspiron 5548 running ubuntu focal?

Tags: hibernate

I'm running Ubuntu Focal and I have 15gigs of Ram and 20G of swap space.

```
Partition: ID-1: / size: 437.52 GiB used: 47.14 GiB (10.8%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda5 
       ID-2: swap-1 size: 19.53 GiB used: 0 KiB (0.0%) fs: swap dev: /dev/sda6
```

I've tried adding acpi=noirq to my grub boot options but it didn't work and it ended up disabling my keyboard.

When I type sudo pm-hibernate and turn the computer back on it starts up normally.

Is there something else I could try?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### To enable Hibernation in 20.04 using swapfile:

**Confirm `swapfile` size matches RAM size**

- Check the swap that is in use:

  ```
  sudo swapon -s
  ```
- If swap partition(s) are found:

  ```
  sudo swapoff -a
  sudo nano -Bw /etc/fstab
  ```
- Add `#` before the `UUID` of the swap partition(s):

  ```
  # UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX   none   swap    sw     0       0
  ```
- Add a line for the `swapfile`, if one does not exist:

  ```
  /swapfile   none    swap     sw      0       0
  ```
- Create the `swapfile`:

  ```
  sudo fallocate -l XG /swapfile*
  ```

  where `X` is `swapfile`'s size in GB:

  ```
  sudo mkswap /swapfile
  sudo chmod 0600 /swapfile
  sudo swapon /swapfile
  ```
- Reboot:

  ```
  sudo reboot
  ```

**Add `resume` location and offset to `grub.cfg`:**

- Edit `/etc/default/grub`:

  ```
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX resume_offset=XXXXX"
  ```
- Use `UUID` from root.
- Use offset from:

  ```
  sudo filefrag -v /swapfile |grep " 0:"| awk '{print $4}'
  ```
- Update GRUB:

  ```
  sudo update-grub
  ```
- Test hibernation:

  ```
  sudo systemctl hibernate
  ```

A hibernate button can be added using GNOME extensions.

Note that there is a slight possibility of getting holes in a `swapfile` when creating it with `fallocate`. `/var/log/syslog` can be searched for the phrase `swapon: swapfile has holes` to ensure there will be no data loss.

A swap file can alternatively be created using `dd`:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/zero of=/swapfile bs=1G count=8
```

**An error when using `dd` may overwrite your HDD.**

Comment: I was using a swap partition. The piece of the puzzle I was missing was "resume=UUID=XXXXXXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXX-XXXXXXXXXXXX" in the Kernel options in the grub config.

Comment: @Frank Barcenas: Thank you for letting us know. I should probably change the instructions to allow for either swap partition or swapfile.

Comment: This guy hibernates. Scratched my head for weeks trying to make hibernation work on my Thinkpad, landed here and got it working in 4 minutes. This is the way.