# Triple booting Windows, Ubuntu, and Fedora

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, swap

I'm trying to triple boot Windows 11, Ubuntu 21.10 and Fedora 34. At the moment, the only OS on my system is Windows 11. How do I go about the install? Also, I had a question about swap partitions - do I need them? (16GB RAM, if that's important) and is it possible to use a common swap partition for Ubuntu and Fedora?

Comment: Even with 16 GB RAM, it is a good idea to have small swap space. However, you can use [ZRAM](https://askubuntu.com/a/233753/124466) instead of traditional swap (which uses HDD/SSD), it is much faster. Then you will not need a common swap partition. Modern versions of Ubuntu (Fedora supports this too) uses a swapfile by default, so you would not need a swap partition anyway. However, if you still want to, you can use a common swap partition (it will be a much slower than ZRAM).

Comment: To install Ubuntu, create a partition, write the ISO to a USB flash drive, and follow https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview. Installation of Fedora is very similar, but Fedora is off-topic on this site.

Comment: A swap file will take up space on both partitions and not be shared.  If you're going to use swap at all, a swap partition is better.  If you create it for one linux, the other may automatically pick it up during install.  You almost never *need* swap, but it sometimes helps a lot.

Comment: Two basic recommendations, I'd install Fedora before Ubuntu, just because I had a problem with Fedora's grub once and Ubuntu's will remain on top if you install it last. And a swap partition can be really helpful even if you don't usually use it. Also, beware Windows can mess up your triple or dual boot configuration whenever it upgrades, it's better to use two separate disks.

Comment: It's also possible to rerun `grub-install` in ubuntu at any time to make it the default grub bootloader for all three operating systems.

Comment: I would suggest using a virtual machine such as VirtualBox or Linux KVM to install other OS on your system instead of converting it into a multiboot OS. I think it is much easier to install or remove any supported OS on virtual machine Rest your choice.

Comment: I'd use a container system like singularity before I ever installed linux as a VM inside another linux.

Comment: So, do swapfiles allow me to close the lid and hibernate?

Comment: To enable Hibernation in 20.04 using swapfile see: https://askubuntu.com/a/1358453/43926

Comment: @C.S.Cameron swap files look pretty cool. Tbh, with how fast Ubuntu boots and shuts down, the only reason I want hibernation is because it is sometimes convenient to just close the lid and get to my next class. I had another question though. If I don't enable hibernation, and my battery suddenly dies, will I lose all my data?

Comment: The power goes off a lot where I live. I usually loose everything only about once in 500 crashes or so. Best to safely unmount any USB drive before removing it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step to setting up a multi-boot system is to decide how you want to distribute the space between the operating systems and decide which partitions you will be sharing between them.

If you are using it, the `efi` partition MUST be shared between all three operating systems.  You may have to enlarge it, but frequently it is large enough by default.

It is possible to share not just `swap` but also `/home` between Ubuntu and Fedora.  However, this could cause issues as shared config files between different versions of the same software may not work well.   If this does become an issue, you can continue sharing `/home` but create a new home directory (spelled differently) for your account in one of the operating systems, and then symlink shared files into the new directory.  (I've shared /home between Ubuntu 18 and 20 without issue before, so it's probably not a big deal.)

It is also possible to share a data partition with windows.  However, the best filesystem format to share between linux and windows is probably `xfat` which would not work well for `/home`.  It might just be better to let linux mount the windows ntfs partition, but this has its own issues.

Once you have decided how to split your space, start by using the windows disk manager to shrink the windows partition.

Then install one of the other two operating systems; use the option to manually partition it, optionally creating `/home` and possibly `swap`, and leaving enough space for the third operating system.

When you install the third operating system, again select the option to manually partition, and create a new partition for `/` and select `/home` and `swap` that already exist, but make sure the option to format them is not selected.   (It is ok to format swap, but if you do, you will have to go back to the second operating system and change the UUID in `/etc/fstab` to match and it may get upset when it can't find it the first time.)  The installer may automatically recognize and select swap for you.

Comment: Best not to try to share /home, but share data partition(s). I use a /mnt/data partition and have multiple LInux installs using it. Back with XP I also had a /mnt/shared as NTFS for some data shared with XP & Linux installs. With no data in /home, it is tiny, mostly hidden configuration files and Firefox & Thunderbird data (which I also move to data partition). Can be same drive: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1013677/storing-data-on-second-hdd-mounting

Comment: I've done that as well and would certainly consider that for sharing with windows.  But like I said, if sharing /home becomes an issue, it's not hard to separate the actual home directories on /home.