# Hibernate in 22.04

Tags: 22.04, suspend, hibernate

I tried to enable the hibernate function after the installation of the 22.04 system. I followed exactly step by step the recommended procedure in [this handbook](https://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2021/08/enable-hibernate-ubuntu-21-10/).

But still, when I push the Hibernate button or enter `systemctl hibernate` in the terminal, the system either just shuts down or the system does not find the swapfile and simply reboots. I checked it time and again, but I cannot find the error. The only irritating issue is: When I enter `swapon --show` I get 2 different answer lines:

```
NAME      TYPE      SIZE USED PRIO
/swapfile file        4G   0B   -2
/dev/dm-2 partition   8G   0B   -3
```

But I have no idea whether it is relevant.

Who knows advice?

Comment: This is the hibernation method that works for me with 22.04: https://askubuntu.com/a/1358453/43926 review fstab for swap location used.

Comment: You did not give any information for saying the method at https://askubuntu.com/a/1358453/43926 does not  work for you. Try adding `sudo` before `systemctl hibernate`. you need to add a password in order to hibernate.